# Cassandra CQL DataType Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I am looking into using Cassandra CQL 3.0 and was reading over the various datatypes provided for tables (or column families). See here for a list of the datatypes: [CQL Datatypes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#cassandra/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj). My questions is what are some advantages and disadvantages of the different datatypes. For example, if I am storing XML into a column, what would be a driver to use blob vs. text?

Comment: I think that your question is to broad. Do you have a specific case that you are seeking the optimal type for?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use blob unless none of the other types makes sense. For XML it would make sense to me to use text.